# Help understanding the difference between "been made" and "being made"

Tags: tense, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

> Where has this product been made? -China.
>
> Where has this product being made? -China.

I know the best question would be something like this: **Where is it made?** . I also know the grammar being used in the above questions. My problem here has to do with simplifying the questions above.

I don't understand the difference in meaning. Even if the grammar is incorrect, please simplify them in simple English, so that I can determine if the structure I have used is correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply say: "Where was this product made?" Or "Is this 'made in China'?" Or "Where is this product from?"

In "Where has this product been made?" they are using [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html). It indicates the action that is completed now.

"Where has this product being made?" is not grammatical. You should write "Where **is** this product being made?" which means the place where they are *currently* producing/making this product.

Comment: Yes, of course. But my concern is to understand how those structures could change the meaning?

Comment: I also vote up to your answer my friend

Comment: @user5036 I edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the second sentence, you cannot mix the "has" and "being made".  It should say
Where is this product being made?

In the first sentence, the past tense implies the product has already been manufactured.  It is complete.
In the second sentence, as I have reworded it, the use of "is" implies that the product is in production now, or will be produced in the future.

Where has this product been made?  It was made in China (two years ago).
Where is this product being made?  In China.  We expect a new shipment to arrive next week.